# Car won’t start

Tags: engine

Well I have a 2016 Chevy Malibu 1.5 turbo and I replaced the engine and now I can’t figure out why it won’t start..when I hit the button the dash light up but won’t make a sound..when I hit the brake to start it I hear a strange noise and the brakes are hard to push..and wondering how could I reset the ecm so the car could register the new engine..has anybody every work in this type of vehicle before that know anything about it..
please help

Comment: If you replaced the engine, literally anything you disconnected and reconnected could be an issue. You seem to have identified the ECM as the problem - do you have error codes you can share?

Comment: Has it started since you replaced the engine?  Because there are like 100 things to replace when you do that, and any of them can be forgotten to be connected, or be a mismatch if you aren't careful about the donor engine.   Is the engine from a different model year? Did you swap anything electrical?  There are so many things that can go wrong with that....

Comment: Was the engine computer or body control module replaced? Is security flashing? Are there any blown fuses? Is there an aftermarket security system?Some factory security systems disable the starting circuit, others disable injectors to prevent theft.